# SQLPLUS Automatically trimming spaces in input values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, input, whitespace, sqlplus

I have an oracle stored procedure that works inside oracle however when I try to run it from sqlplus it does not work because the input value it takes in requires two spaces between the words. SQLPLUS automatically truncates this to a single space, for example.

```
 sqlplus username/password @setup_run.sql 'Word1__Word2'

 old   5:   inparam1 := '&1';
 new   5:   inparam1 := 'Word1_Word2';

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

How do I stop this from happening? I do not want to manually parse the string and add a space because for other inputs that do not have the space this would cause issues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not sqlplus that does that, it's probably the system|shell. Windows XP does it for example, you can fix it by using double-quotes.

```
sqlplus username/password @setup_run.sql "Word1  Word2"
```